# Create a new java package in eclipse (apart from default package), but can not use the class from external library in the files in this new folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I create a new java package in eclipse (apart from default package), but can not use the class from external library in the files in this new folder?

So it basically means a new folder in the src folder. All the java files in this new folder can not use external libraries which I have no problem to use in files from src.

src
  -(default package)
    -Hello.java
  - com.kensupernova.extra
    -Extra.java
JRE System Library
Referenced Libraries
  -algs4.jar
  -stdlib.jar

Comment: Are the external classes on the same classpath as the code you're using them with?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You can use any class on your build path from anywhere in your project; so if you can use them from your default package, you can also use them from anywhere else in that project. Please clarify what you mean by "can not use", and please tell us exactly how you created this new package. Maybe you created a whole new *project*...?

Comment: i do not know. i had added external library to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Ctrl+Shift+o`? If that does not work, type in the path yourself?

If that doesn't work then post a screenshot of the package hierarchy, lots more people would be able to help you from there.

Comment: i am new to Stackoverflow, not enough reputation to post images. I added external .jar library to the project.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know what your problem may be, I've worked with jars before and I never had a problem.

Comment: How do you create a new package and use the jar in the new package?

Comment: I just type press Ctrl+Shift+o and it works, what version of eclipse are you running?

Comment: Thank you. I finally figured out. Ctrl+Shift+o (in OSX). I used to replace ctrl with cmd. How silly I am. Thanks again.